# How do I specify optional modules in MacOS in Gnucash?

Tags: gnucash

I'm trying to import invoices. On MacOS where do I specify

(gnc:module-load "gnucash/plugins/bi_import" 0)

as noted in 
https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v3/C/gnucash-guide/import-invoices.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document you cite contains the answer- $HOME/.gnucash/config.user, which should also exist in your home directory on MacOS.  Folder names starting with a dot (.) are hidden by default, so you might need to type it into the address bar.

Comment: ⌘⇧. (Command-shift-period) in finder or a file dialog will show hidden/dot files.